# get value from database using java

Tags: java, database

This code doesnt work , please helpp , i want to read value from database and I have one condition .

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/joebdd";

String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

String user = "root";

String pass = "12345";     

String value=(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());

     try

{

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();


Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);


String sql1 = "select Price from Produit where ProductName='"+value+"'";

PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql1);

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) pst.executeQuery(sql1);


 jTextField3.setText(rs.getString(1));


    }


catch(  ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | 

SQLException e){

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

}}
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace? Also, don't embed your `value` in the query, but use the prepared statement that you're already using.

Comment: How does it not work? You getting errors/exceptions? You are not getting the desired result? _"It doesn't work"_ with out more context, is never a good description of your problem

Comment: If you're going to use `PreparedStatement`, use it correctly.. **1** use `?` for your parameters **2** use `setXxx` to get the arguments for the parameters. **3** to obtain the result set use `executeQuery()` with _no_ arguments.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting any exceptions? or you are not getting any values?...and just for the reminder have you set the mySql class path for your server ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that `ResultSet` has any value or not, by `rs.next()`.

```
    String pass = "12345";     
    String value=(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        String sql1 = "select Price from Produit where ProductName='"+value+"'";

        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) pst.executeQuery(sql1);
        if(rs.next())
        {
            jTextField3.setText(rs.getString(1));
        }
        else
        {
            jTextField3.setText("");
        }

    }
    catch(  ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```